# Guess an explicit formula for recursively defined sequence

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Was given this as a question.

"Use iteration to guess an explicit formula for the recursively defined sequence and then prove that the formula is a solution to the recurrence using induction:

$a_{k} = ka_{k-1}$, for all integers k>1     $a_{0} = 1$"

(English: a sub k equals k times a sub k minus one, a sub zero equals 1)

The problem with this question is I cannot determine a ratio as k is equal to the index of the sequence. Given this equation I get the sequence:

1,1,2,6,24,120

It is obvious to me that I need the result of the previous index and multiply it by the current one. I tried using geometric and arithmetic sequencing methods, however, the partial sum of a geometric sequence doesn't account for the +1 increase in what otherwise is a constant ratio. I cannot find any such instance of this question anywhere and I believe the question is incomplete, but if I have the right info, where do I go?

Comment: Look at your sequence more carefully. 1,1,2,6,24,120. 6 is 3*2, 24 is 4*6, 120 is 5*24, etc. It really looks like $a_{k}=k!$.

Comment: Forget about ratios, they'll not help you here. Are you familiar with factorials? If not, give them a quick wiki.

Comment: Factorials? Oh no, there's nothing about factorials in our home work, coursework, or lectures to indicate that I would have to bother with that! I've only spent too many hours trying to answer this question in the context of the chapter... At least I can stop thinking I've completely missed the point on this chapter. Time for a quick wiki! :)

Comment: Factorial has a very simple definition. You can call it $\prod_{u = 1}^{k}u = k!$ (for positive k)

Comment: So my Explicit Formula is: a sub n  = n(n!-1)?

Comment: No, it is just n!

Comment: I don't know how to prove that with induction =/

Answer (score 3):

The induction hypothesis is $a_n = \prod\limits_{k=1}^nk.$ This is true for the base case as $a_0 = 1$.

Now $a_{n+1} = (n+1)a_n = (n+1)\prod\limits_{k=1}^nk = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}k$, which proves the hypothesis.

Comment: (+1)...I want someone to answer $a_n=\Gamma(n+1)$